# What is the purpose of `scala-2.11` folder in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

scala-2.11 folder appeared after recent update of IDEA and Scala plugin.
What should it be used for?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Usually such directories are used for binary version-dependent code. For example, macros in 2.10 are not source-compatible with macros in 2.11, so if you're building your project for different binary versions and you're using macros, it makes sense to put code which is only valid for the specific version in different source roots. SBT then will use the appropriate directory when compiling for 2.10 or 2.11.

If you're using SBT, though, you would need to set such thing up manually in the build definition. If you're not using SBT, then probably IDEA plugin was updated to handle such things by itself.

Comment: "If you're using SBT, though, you would need to set such thing up manually in the build definition" No, this is part of SBT 0.13.8: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1799

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks for clarification. It's obviously SBT related. :)

Comment: So where should I put my code when I'm using only scala 2.11 compatible features of language?

Comment: @onegrx, put all your code to `scala` if you only need to support 2.11. If you need your code to compile on both 2.10 and 2.11, put incompatible things to their respective directories (`scala-2.11` and `scala-2.10`) and compatible things (i.e. those which can be shared between versions) to `scala`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: How can I tell SBT not to add those folders as long as I don't need them?

Comment: @Make42 Just disable "Create directories for empty content roots automatically" when importing/creating the project.

Comment: The option to tell SBT after project creation not to create empty directories can be found under "File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deploxment > Build Tools > SBT > Create directories for empty content roots automatically".