# Why does Intellij create multiple scala code directories (scala, scala-2.10, scala-2.11) etc?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

What is the reason that Intellij (or is that sbt?) creates not a single scala source directory, but multiple?

Comment: Probably you have references to 2.10 and 2.11 libraries in your sbt

Comment: Or probably you migrated from 2.10 to 2.11 without nuking all the target directories?

Answer (score 1):

SBT doesn't create the directories, but it recognizes them: [code in `scala` will be compiled for all Scala versions, `scala-2.10` and `scala-2.11` are for version-dependent code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444898/what-is-the-purpose-of-scala-2-11-folder-in-intellij-idea) So when you import SBT project (or create a new one) and have "Create directories for empty content roots automatically" option checked, it makes sense for IDEA to create them (I don't know if it always does).